# How to convert member of class list to List<String> in one line code?

Tags: list, flutter

I have a `List<MyClass> myClass;`, I want to get `List<String> myList;` from all of myClass.item, is there one line way to convert it?

Comment: read `List.map` official documentation (and `Iterable` documentation in general)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the map method from List class to loop through the entire list. Don't forget to call toList in the end, as Dart's map returns a kind of Iterable. Please see the code below.

```
class Employee {
  int id;
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  Employee(
    this.id,
    this.firstName,
    this.lastName,
  );
}

void main() {
  List<Employee> employees = <Employee>[
    Employee(1, "Adam", "Black"),
    Employee(2, "Adrian", "Abraham"),
    Employee(3, "Alan", "Allan"),
  ];

  List<String> myList = employees.map((item)=>item.firstName).toList();
  print(myList);
}
```

Comment: How can I do if I just need `["Adam", "Adrian", "Alan"]`?

Comment: Updated my answer please see the code above.